# how to use data from a firestore collection to calculate a cost?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a program in Kotlin to get a bunch of prices of a Firestore database and sum and multiply them to calculate the total price Example: x persons * x Days * (restaurant cost[chosen from a document of Firestore which describes the city] + transport cost of different places[there are 15 places of destination and 23 of start with 3 options of transport each, in a Firestore document again]) and then show all the possibilities that cost less than the introduced budget
the problem is I'm rather new to programming and I do not know how to do this. the only thing that comes to mind is to create a loop that starts making the operations and saving the results on an ArrayList and then showing the ArrayList in the activity, the thing is, I do not know how to through all the possibilities and how to store every result on the ArrayList. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice(I'm not looking for the entire code, I'm trying to learn) on how to do this or maybe a tutorial I could follow to do this. thanks to all in advance

Also, when I'm trying to access the data from a document in Firestore an error that says "For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method" This is the code that gives the error:

```
var data = ""

db.collection("city")
    .document("places").collection("restaurant")
    .document("little bistro")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result//here is where the error is) {
            data = document["price"].toString()
            calc = data.toInt() + 100

        }
        txtresult.setText(calc.toString())
    }
    .addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
        txtresult.setText("fail")

    }


EDIT

if (place == "no preferences" && quality) {
                    var data = ""
                    db.collection("city")
                        .document("places").collection("restaurant")
                        .document("little bistro")
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                            for (document in result.documents) {
                                data = document["price"].toString()
                                calc = data.toInt() + 100

                            }
                            txtresult.setText(calc.toString())
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
                            txtresult.setText("fail")

                        }

                }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: yes, the problem is here: for (document in (result/ this is the word that gets the error)//here is where the error is). the error says: "For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method". also im seeking for guidance for what i want to do, as i described above.

Comment: What's the edit for as the parameters in the for...loop changed before and after the edit. Please clarify the question and what the trouble is (update the QUESTION please; don't add comments trying to clarify it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> "For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method"

At the following line of code:

```
for (document in result) { //Here is the error.
    data = document["price"].toString()
    calc = data.toInt() + 100
}
```

Because the `result` object is an object of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot). When you want to read a document, there is no need to iterate through the result object. So you have to remove the for-loop and directly use:

```
db.collection("city")
    .document("places").collection("restaurant")
    .document("little bistro")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        data = snapshot.getString("price")
        calc = data.toInt() + 100
        txtresult.setText(calc.toString())
    }
    .addOnFailureListener{ exception ->
        txtresult.setText("fail")

    }
```

I have also renamed the `result` object into `snapshot`, as it makes more sense.

Comment: when i add the ".documents" to result it tells me that is an unresolved reference

Comment: It should not. Please edit your question and show us the changed code.

Comment: i added the changes in the question

Comment: I see, you're reading just a document. So please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! i had to add a .toString after ("price") but now is working. aside from that if know any video or documentation on how to do the things i mentioned above i would really apreciate it, im kinda lost on where to find sources to learn about kotlin. and thank you very much again for the help

Comment: You're very welcome. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Besides that, maybe this [resources](https://medium.com/@alex.mamo) will help. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) in particular will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Comment: no thanks, thats all i needed